# How to retain Top N while applying a legend in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to show my top 15 Buyers and grouping the rest of the buyers in the "Others" category. For this, I have made a Psuedo Table

```
Psuedo Buyer Table = UNION(
    DISTINCT('tbl1'[Buyer]),
    DATATABLE("Buyer",STRING,{{"Others"}})
)
```

I have joined my Psuedo table to tbl1 by Many to 1 relationship(Single), and created the following measure:

```
TopNBuyers_15 = 
VAR TopBuyerTable = 
TOPN(15,ALLSELECTED('Psuedo Buyer Table'),[ID_count])
VAR TopBuyerID = CALCULATE([ID_count],KEEPFILTERS(TopBuyerTable))
VAR otherscount = CALCULATE([ID_count],ALLSELECTED('Psuedo Buyer Table'))-CALCULATE([ID_count],TopBuyerTable)
VAR currentBuyer = SELECTEDVALUE('Psuedo Buyer Table'[Buyer])
RETURN 
IF(currentBuyer<>"Others",TopBuyerID,otherscount)
```

This is working in a way that it is giving me top 15 buyers in my bar chart with one extra bar called "Others". However when I am applying a LEGEND to this bar chart, it is behaving in other way,and giving me top 15 for each of that value in the legend.

Expected:
Those Top 15 is retained on applying that legend ( column: Status). I mean, my top 15 should ONLY be dependent on my `ID_count` and be unaffected by Status.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I know this is a sort of non-answer, but [Alberto Ferrari showed how to do this in a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVvlEHKr_0o&t=83s) on YouTube

Comment: I did go through this video and the whole data model becomes really complex :( Thank you for replying anyway!:)

Comment: I tried his way however he used SUMX and I need a distinct count sum for calculating my "Others" column. Would you have a way to do that?

Comment: Did you try removing the filter for Status in your visual? (You'd create a measure and do something like CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),REMOVEFILTERS('Table'[Status]))

Comment: Where exactly do you think I should put this in my DAX Query above?